# Write a function called 'maker' that creates an array and fills that array with numbers 1 to 25, then returns the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

**Question** 
Write a function called 'maker' that creates an array and fills that array with numbers 1 to 25, then returns the array.

I'm stuck on this problem. I've watched a bunch of videos, and read various forms. However I can't seem to figure it out. Can anyone help me?

**My attempt**

```
var myArray = [1-25]

function maker(arr) {
return myArray
}
```

Comment: `const maker=()=>Array.from({length:25},(_,i)=>i+1)`

Comment: ```let myArray = Array(25).fill(0).map((_, i) => i + 1)```

Comment: You really should go through some basic JavaScript tutorials to learn the fundamentals of the language. As it is, you're trying to jump into a coding task without any idea of what you're doing. No offense intended! We all start out as newbies in any new endeavor. But start with the basics and learn about `for` loops. I _do not recommend_ either of the fancy solutions proposed in the previous comments until you understand more. Those are nifty, but you should start out with the most basic and simple approach: inside `maker`, create an empty array and then `push()` the required values onto it.

Comment: @MichaelGeary If you're going to create a fixed length array anyway then it's better to simply assign the values instead of pushing them. Pushing values is only appropriate when you don't know the length of the array beforehand, like when you're filtering an array.

Comment: @AaditMShah I should have made it more clear that I didn't mean to be critical of the very interesting solution you posted in your comment! My only real point was that we're talking with someone who is just at the very beginning of their understanding of how to write a program. (No offense, JohnDoe99, we all start out as newbies!) At this point, it doesn't matter whether they use `array.push(value)` or `array[i] = value` or a more functional solution. It's way too early to worry about which may be more efficient - this is more of a place for basic understanding, like how to write a `for` loop.

Comment: No worries. I didn't take offense to anything you said anyway. I just wanted to point out that it's better to use `new Array(25)` and `array[i] = value` when the length of the array is known. In fact, I posted the same comment on the answer below.

Comment: And just to clarify (since I ran out of characters in my comment), it's good for someone to be exposed to all of these different kinds of approaches. I really think a simple `for` loop is a great place to start, because it helps you see how things work "under the hood" when you use the more clever functional methods.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function maker() {
  var myArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    myArray[i] = i + 1;
  }
  return myArray;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your loop condition should be `i < 25`. Also, I suggest that you define `myArray` as `new Array(25)`. It's faster and better practice.

Comment: @AaditMShah Thanks, you are right about the condition. I was trying to decide between `i < 25` and `i <= 24`, and I guess I accidentally mixed the two. About the declaration, I agree, but I was trying to use the same format as in the question.